# ignore first occurance of letter regex

Tags: python, regex

using the following strings

```
    9989S90K72MF-1
    9989S90S-1
    9989S75K60MF-1
    9989S75S-1
```

I Would like to extract the below from those strings.

```
    9989S90
    9989S90
    9989S75
    9989S75
```

So far I have:

```
(^.*?(?=K|-))
```

Which gives me:

```
    9989S90
    9989S90S
    9989S75
    9989S75S
```

Here's a link https://regex101.com/r/d1nQj0/1

I've tried a few different regex but can't seem to nail it. Is there a way to ignore the first occurrence of a digit/letter? Which in my case would be `S`

Comment: Looks like you just want the first 7 characters from each line, unless there are other requirements? Could you just use `(^.{7})`?

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington I had thought about using this but what I need to capture isnt necessarily the same upto the 7th character throughout the data.. Thank you

Comment: Okay, are you looking to match a string containing a single `S` and up to either an `S` or `K`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex matches a string at the beginning of a line that contains a single S up to but not including the first occurrence of S or K

```
^(.*?S.*?)(?=K|S)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example data, you could also match 1+ digits, then `S` followed by 1+ digits.

```
^\d+S\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j920Bm/3)

If there has to be a `S` `K` or `-` at the right:

```
^\d+S\d+(?=[KS-])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j920Bm/4)

Example

```
import re

regex = r"^\d+S\d+(?=[KS-])"

s = ("9989S90K72MF-1\n"
    "9989S90S-1\n"
    "9989S75K60MF-1\n"
    "9989S75S-1")

print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['9989S90', '9989S90', '9989S75', '9989S75']
```